How do you get pydub to find ffmpeg?
I'm trying to import pydub into my python program but any time I run the code it says it can't locate where ffmpeg is. I have tried everything including putting "pip install ffmpeg-python" in command prompt, juggling around the locations of the ffmpeg and python files, changing the system environment lables in PATH (although this is not saving for some reason)
I don't know what to do from here
My exact code from before would've looked like this:
import pydub
import ffmpeg
from pydub import AudioSegment
trumpet = AudioSegment.from_mp3("C:/Users/*redacted*/Downloads/trumpet-e4-14829.mp3")
pydub.playback.play(trumpet)

And I got this beautiful long error message:
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\*redacted*\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 170
    warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*redacted*\pydub test.py", line 4, in <module>
    trumpet = AudioSegment.from_mp3("C:/Users/*redacted*/Downloads/trumpet-e4-14829.mp3")
  File "C:\Users\*redacted*\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 796, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
  File "C:\Users\*redcated*\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 651, in from_file
    file, close_file = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(file, 'rb', tempfile=False)
  File "C:\Users\*redacted*\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 60, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/*redacted*/Downloads/trumpet-e4-14829.mp3'


PyDub simply searches ffmpeg.exe binary in %PATH%.

Installing FFmpeg. The docs is from ffmpeg-python repository; you actually don't need ffmpeg-python, only ffmpeg.exe. Try https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows
